# Rails 3.1 + Heroku Cedar - Static image assets are not being served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed a Rails 3.1 application on Heroku Cedar. For some reason my static image assets are not being served:

```
2011-06-23T18:14:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/me_reminder-30f9d1dead32e12238888adbee4b92d3.png" for 98.207.60.248 at 2011-06-23 18:14:13 +0000
2011-06-23T18:14:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Served asset /me_reminder-30f9d1dead32e12238888adbee4b92d3.png - 200 OK (0ms) (pid 1)
2011-06-23T18:14:13+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/me_reminder-30f9d1dead32e12238888adbee4b92d3.png] miss, store
2011-06-23T18:14:13+00:00 heroku[router]: GET xxxx.herokuapp.com/assets/me_reminder-30f9d1dead32e12238888adbee4b92d3.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=0
```

As you can see, it is returning something with 0 bytes. Needless to say, no image shows.

However, all my other static assets (css, javascripts) are being served correctly. Any idea what could be wrong here?

By the way, I have another Rails 3.1 app on heroku which is working just fine, so I don't think it's a problem with sprockets, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem. In `config/environments/production.rb` file, comment:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

And instead, have:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = nil # For Heroku
```

This is also the recommended way of doing this. As suggested in the [Heroku docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#serving_assets_from_your_application).

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me crazy. The docs you link to do not mention this change, but clearly they should.

Comment: That's strange. They must have rewritten the docs. Last time I checked, it was there.. Odd indeed. Glad it helped you

Comment: Works for me in my Rails 2 instance. I'd be interested to know why.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. changing production.rb file configuration to

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

from

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

worked for me. since Heroku uses nginx in front.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran into this same issue and this resolved it for me.

Comment: This worked for me too and there's definitely no mention of it in Heroku's docs for 3.1

Comment: This may not always work: see the [Heroku docs on Rack::Sendfile](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-sendfile).

Comment: Heroku does not have NGINX in front of cedar apps.

Comment: @Schneems That's false. Cedar uses nginx, but it is not on the same server as your Rails app. That is why `X-Accel-Redirect` cannot be used on Heroku reliably.

Comment: @ChrisPeters I work for Heroku, i also wrote a book on Heroku http://shop.oewreilly.com/product/0636920027409.do so trust me when i say that Cedar does not have NGINX. You could put it in front of your apps if you use a custom buildpack, but the Ruby buildpack does not use NGINX and our runtime instances do not have that software by default. What makes you think it is available?

Comment: @Schneems I guess it was a blog post by your book's co-author that threw me off. :) http://www.neilmiddleton.com/heroku-asset-pipeline-faq/ Maybe the comment about Nginx is outdated or incorrect? `"X-Accel-Redirect" is also a good value for this since Heroku use Nginx.`

Comment: @Schneems Either way, thanks for clarifying/correcting me. And I'm sorry for a moment of weakness asserting something as strongly as "that's false." That was very dickish of me.

Comment: I understand now, that code comment is not correct. Our Bamboo Stack had NGINX so likely that comment was likely true when written but not updated when the app was migrated to Cedar. Notice that the code directly below it contradicts the comment by using a different value. Hope this clears some things up.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I was referring to images in the asset pipeline using HTML. Example:

```
<img src="/assets/hello.jpg" />
```

The image assets would work locally but not on Heroku. Switching over to using Rails' `image_tag` view helper solved the issue. Example:

```
<%= image_tag "hello.jpg" %>
```

Comment: how would you do it with CSS? :D

Comment: @DeG exact question I had.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, there can be some unexpected behavior using images in the asset pipeline. To avoid it, you can leave them in `public/` just like previous versions of rails.

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1209).

Comment: Hm, my other application doesn't have the images in public/images, and everything is working correctly. I tried to copy everything into public but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: To be honest, I'm really not very familiar with the nature of the problem, as I've never encountered it myself. What prompted me to point you to that discussion is the fact that your issue is occurring on Heroku, where the app is (I'm assuming) being run in production mode. The issue I pointed you to specifically deals with static image assets not being served correctly (or at least as expected) through the asset pipeline when switching to production mode.

Comment: Sure, I understand, thanks. And the discussion is very recent so I was pretty optimistic it would solve my problem :) Turns out it didn't though.

Comment: As was I. Did you make sure your URL helper methods were correct when you moved the images to `public/`?

Comment: Yeah, it worked locally, I made sure I put them in the right place. Anyway, I found [this discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1822), which describes the exact issue I am having. For some reason even setting caching to false doesn't fix it for me though. Also, I am at a loss why it works for my other app which has an almost identical configuration except for a few unrelated gems (such as devise). It's also on heroku.